# Download a file from a direct URL to a different folder once in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, file-download

I'm trying to download a large file but my default download folder does not have enough space. Normally, we can right-click on a link and choose the destination, but I do not have a link; I have the direct download URL.

Is there a way I can direct Chrome to download this file to a specific location? When I paste it into the address bar and "go", it just uses the default download folder.

Comment: Change the default download folder (chrome://settings/downloads). When it completes, change it back.